# Is it possible to combine cryptography with steganography

Tags: steganography

*Definitions:*
**M** - original message,
**Me** - encrypted message **M**,
**S** - watermark message,
**Ms** - message **M** with steganography watermark **S**,
**e** - encryption private key,
**d** - decryption key (it is private too),
**s** - key for signing message with watermark,
**ds** - decryption public key, inseparable combined with watermark key **s**,
**v** - key for verify watermark **S** in message **Ms**.

*Here is the task:*

Alice generates two keys **e** and **d**, so:
**(M, e) = Me** and **(Me, d) = M**

Then Alice generates keys **s** and **v** for watermarking message with **S** and verifying it:
**(M, s) = Ms** and **(Ms, v) = S**

After that Alice takes decryption key **d** and combines it with **s**, so:
**(d, s) = ds** and there is no **F** that could **F(ds) = d**

Then Alice sends **Me** to Bob by unsecured public channels.
And Alice gives **ds** to Bob by secured private channel.

Bob can read **Me** by applying key **ds**, so:
**(Me, ds) = Ms**
Bob *cannot do* and there is no **F** to:
**F(Me) = M** or **F(Ms) = M**

And Bob shares message **Ms** to public channels.

Now Alice have found message **Ms** and can verify that message has been shared by Bob, like this:
**(Ms, v) = S**

Is someone here knows is it able and exists some algorithms to do that,
may be some implementation of it, and how to combine existing encryption and watermarking libraries?

Comment: I assume there's an unstated requirement that Alice should be able to send the same encrypted message to multiple recipients, each having their own decryption key, and have them each obtain a distinct watermarked copy when they decrypt it? And presumably also that each decryption ḱey can be safely used to decrypt arbitrarily many messages, without allowing the watermark to be removed? Is it also possible for the recipients to collude to defeat the watermark? (In reality, it generally is, but it tends to make designing reliable watermarks much harder.)

Comment: The question prescribes no relation between **M** and **Ms**; but that's going to be central to the usability of the system, and dependent on the nature of **M** used in practice. With complete design freedom about what **Ms** can be, it might possible to craft something, but it will be of no practical use that I can discern. If **Ms** is to be as produced by some arbitrary watermarking algorithm taking into account the nature of **M**, I very much doubt that what's asked can be done with a public decrypt-and-watermark algorithm. $\;$ As an aside, is **v** public or secret?

Comment: By principle, stenography is there when  the job of cryptography  is done

Comment: @IlmariKaronen yes,"each obtain a distinct watermarked copy when they decrypt it", and there is no need for decrypt many messages by one key, keys can be generated many times.

Comment: @IlmariKaronen about defeating the watermark, now I am trying to understand what algorithms exists to watermark data

Comment: If each key only needs to be able to decrypt one message, why not put the watermarked message for each recipient in their "key", and just use a dummy "message"? (OK, one possible reason is if you need to be able to generate the keys before you know the message.)

Comment: Alternative "solution": Generate a bunch of watermarked versions **Ms** of the message **M**, encrypt each of them with the corresponding recipient's key (you can use standard symmetric or public-key crypto here) and combine all the encrypted messages into **Me**. Each recipient just extracts the piece of **Me** that is encrypted with their key, and decrypts it. Obviously, this produces a very long **Me** if there are lots of recipients, but otherwise it seems to meet your requirements.

Comment: The question's title is not clear there are multiple ways to combine cryptography and steganography. Some are quite common. Almost always we encrypt data before hiding and embedding it inside some cover data. Or, it makes sense to utilize steganography when we need to share a common key. The method discussed here is just one type of combining these two. Please make your question's title more specific and clear.